# If I create an android app, will it work on windows 7 chrome browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, windows-7

I want to use phonegap to create an app that will work on both mobile and desktop. Looks like it will work on windows 8, but I'm not sure if I can get it working on windows 7 by using chrome. Are android apps installable on windows 7 chrome browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the android stuff won't be installable on chrome.
You might want to look at https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps.

This works like Cordova but helps you building Chrome apps but also usable on mobile, which is what you want I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you use phonegap to develop a mobile app, that means you want to use html,css,javascript, surely it will work on any browser. No matter that is win 7 or win 8, chrome or firefox! Untill you are using Cordova.js or phonegap.js features like deviceready functions or mobile plugins etc.